# Is it less efficient to share the same switch statement in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, switch-statement

I would like to know if my approach is efficient. Please take a look at these feed readers that fetch feeds by using select options' data attributes to find the selected feed in the `switch statement`. Suppose each select box will display five feeds from different sources so it is going to have 10 cases, given that feeds usually come in different format. The part I'm not sure of is whether it's a good idea for these two select boxes to share the same statement and for each to unnecessarily go through half of the unrelated cases? Is it possible to have two switch statements for each select boxes?

```
 function parseData(type, data) {

   var item_html = '';
   var YQLpath = data.query.results;

    switch(type) {

        case 'Yahoo':
            $(YQLpath.Question).each(function (index, Question) {
                item_html += '<li><a target="_blank" href="' + Question.Link + '">' + Question.Subject + '</a></li>';
            });
            break;
        case 'Google':
            $(YQLpath.item).each(function (index, item) {

             var findImg = item.description;

             var img = $(findImg).find('img').eq(0).attr('src');

             var text = $(findImg).find("div.lh").children("font:nth-of-type(2)").text().substr(0, 150) + '...';

             item_html += '<li><a target="_blank" href="' + item.link + '">' + item.title + '</a>';

            });

            break;
    }
    return item_html;
 }
});
```

Comment: Please also show the code of the `switch` statement!

Comment: Since `<select>` `change` events are quite infrequent, you will not notice any performance differences. Use what is more readable and more maintainable.